# Navbar - When nav-item is 2 words, second word goes below

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to finalize the navbar using bootstrap and when i specify the nav.item name, in this case "Our company", the second word, i.e. the company goes below. any idea why and how i can fix it:

```html
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class ="mylogo" src="images/logo+text.png" alt="My logo"></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#footer">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#cta">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see any "Our company" word in your code. Could you please check and please draw a diagram/picture of what you want your Nav bar looks like.

Answer (score 1):

So i can't write a comment, but would mind sharing the css to this? There can be a few possibilities here

1. Word-wrap can be set to break-word
2. Not enough space within the navigation item. Like if its a strict width (i.e: .nav-link {width: 300px}) when it should be set to width: auto;
3. The .navbar-nav can also be have a set width that doesn't allow for the nav-items to grow.

I would probably look into flex-box because of how the name suggests it flexible and I've used it countless of times in navigation areas. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ is a great guide and visual on how it works!

If you can please edit your question and add some css so I can really help you out here! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using &nbsp to insert the space between the words [HTML space in navigation bar list item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Jgl.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).